# unable to pass entries from an embed txt file into an array list

Tags: c#, file

I am trying to follow this thread:
[How to read embedded resource text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file)

However I am not able to make it work.

Goal:
From a txt file that it is embed on the project which has a list of names.
Read all the entries, store them on an array list of strings.

Current set up of the file:
[image]

Current code based on the linked thread:

```
            var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

            using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(TownGame.Properties.Resources.m_names))
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

Which is the best way to fill out:

```
public string[] names_list = new string[20];  //list of names
```

With the content of the embed m_names.txt file?

---

Changed the original code for this:
This is in a debugging, The streamer is NULL still the file has content as shown with the mouse over the n_names.txt

[image]

Comment: Why not use what you're getting with your StreamReader..? As its name suggests, it's reading the file. So instead of reading it all at one with `ReadToEnd`, read it line by line and put that in you array.

Comment: sorry not sure how to do it, the problem is that:  
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream)) is not working at all, I am not sure how to use properly, the getManifiestResourceStream @DangerZone

Comment: What do you mean it is not working? Are you getting an error or exception? What is happening?

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll  

Additional information: Value cannot be null.  

it is failing this:
Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(TownGame.Properties.Resources.m_names)  

any idea why?

Comment: If you debug the program, at that line is `TownGame.Properties.Resou‌​rces.m_names` null?

Comment: Please share the exception stack trace and also show on which line this occurs.

Comment: changed the original code a little bit, still having problem with streamer as null